# Can't get access to controls from code behind in pcl part of xamarin forms project

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, code-behind, xforms

I've got **Xamarin.Forms** project with pcl-part and native win, ios and android parts.
All page structure and view-models are in pcl-part. App work's fine, but when I'm trying for example to hide Grid from code behind - it do nothing. Here is code example:

**Xaml**:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="SomeNamespase.SomePage">

    <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" BackgroundColor="Green">
        <Frame x:Name="InnerContent"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**.cs** :

```
using System;

namespace SomeNamespase
{
    public partial class SomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            this.InnerGrid.IsVisible = false;
            this.InnerContent.BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua;           
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried `this.FindByName<Grid>("InnerGrid");` the same result

Note: if I am trying to get controls from action in PCL everything is good. Nothing going on when I'm trying to get controls from ViewPresenter in windows (or other platforms) project.

Comment: Have you tried binding the Visibility of the Grid to a property in the ViewModel?

Comment: Yes, unfortionatly also not helped

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, are the lines of code executing?

Comment: Yes, in debug mode code is running thru all lines, but nothing going on

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are properly implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, as in your code I can't see the constructor.

```
using System;

namespace SomeNamespase
{
    public partial class SomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public SomePage() 
       {
            SomeMethod() ;
       } 
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            this.InnerGrid.IsVisible = false;
            this.InnerContent.BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua;           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not full code example, the constructor is over there. But method should be used not in constuctor but in runtime, when we are using one of interface implemented method